# sort and save with bookshelf.js

Tags: sql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a table that I want to sort by name in ascending order.
I tried to do it this way, but it didn't help:

```
return this.Model.query((qb) => {
  qb.orderBy('contentName', 'ASC');
}).save();
```

What am I missing, I feel like it shouldn't be so hard, but I just can't make it work. The bookshelf.js doc didn't really help me. I am a beginner here, so this could be the reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save()` is only for inserting/updating data. For fetching data from queries we use `fetch()` for single models or `fetchAll()` for collections. So try changing your code to:

```
return this.Model.query((qb) => {
  qb.orderBy('contentName', 'ASC');
}).fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I actually want the data to be updated, so I don't need to sort whenever I'm fetching the data.
Would be also fine to just know how to sort the table when inserting new data.

Comment: You mean you want to replace the data on a table by the same data, but ordered? If yes this is not the way relational databases work: the physical placement of rows if very implementation dependent and there are no guarantees of the order data will be brought back without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Alright then, I will keep using orderBy when fetching the data then. Thank you for the info!